# sudo suddenly stopped working on debian

Tags: debian, sudo

I've been using 'sudo ' since I setup my server about a week ago.

It suddently stopped working with no explanation.

I am in 'sudo' group. So there should be no config change required to /etc/sudoers

```
$ sudo apt-get install tsocks
[sudo] password for me: 
me is not in the sudoers file.


root@host:/etc# groups me
me : me sudo
```

The only thing it could possibly be related to was I added the following line to sshd_config:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

But I have since changed that back to

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Permission on file is 400:

```
ls -l /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- 1 root root 491 Sep 28 21:52 /etc/sudoers
```

Here is visudo output:

```
Defaults        env_reset
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I'm in the sudo group in /etc/group, i used $ usermod -G sudo me

```
sudo:x:27:me
```

No idea why it stopped working, or how to fix it.

Comment: Permission on the /etc/sudoers is 440 as you have displayed it.  But that is ok.

Comment: sudo does not necessarily use group membership to provide access, it looks like your sudoers file has been changed somehow.

Comment: @mdpc, the stock Debian config includes a directive like `%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL`.  The stock config is also 491 bytes on my system.

Comment: i updated question with my file.

Comment: Do you have physical access to the console?  Do you have any other access to the root account? You may need to go into rescue mode so you can inspect the auth logs and see if any errors are getting logged.

Comment: Yes, I can 'su' to the root user.

Answer (score 0):

Type 'visudo' and check, if your user is added there - probably not.
Search for a line, which consists something like:

```
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

For your user you should have something similar in visudo.

Comment: You shouldn't have to add the user explicitly to /etc/sudeors if you are in the sudo group. Works fine on my other system, I can sudo w/o having my name in /etc/sudoers. And like I said, this just stopped working.

Answer (score -2):

Ok I don't know what is going on, but I just rebooted my server and now sudo works fine.

Comment: That's something you should have tried *before* posting the question.

Comment: why? afaik, sudo doesn't require a reboot. Why would a reboot fix the problem?

Comment: Clearly something went wrong. Rebooting is what you try when you can find no apparent reason for a problem.